# how to make the box shadow in the stack with touch events

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image]

in the above picture, there is a stack widget with 3 layers.
Images
Pure Veg
Like And More buttons

If you focus on the image you will notice the image has some box shadow in the top corner and behind the buttons. and the shadow helps to make the visibility of buttons

I tried to add the box shadow but if i add the shadow then the image is not clickable in that area

I need to achieve the image onTap event, box-shadow, Button visibility, button onTap event

and this is my code

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
    topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
    topRight: Radius.circular(15),
  ),
  child: SizedBox(
    height: 200,
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        PageView.builder(
          itemCount: fc.restaurants[i].images.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey[
                          Get.isDarkMode ? 800 : 200]!,
                      spreadRadius: 1,
                      blurRadius: 5,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                child: CustomImage(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  placeholder:
                      'assets/image/placeholder.png',
                  image: fc.restaurants[i].images[index],
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        // box shadow only on the top corer
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(0.5)
              ..scale(1.8)
              ..translate(33.0, -10.0),
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              width: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  end: Alignment.topLeft,
                  colors: [
                    Colors.transparent,
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const Positioned(
          top: 10,
          right: 10,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.favorite_border,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 24,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              ),
              Icon(
                Icons.more_vert,
                color: Colors.white,
                size: 24,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: try to place the clickable widget as last child

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh if i did this then the pageview not scrollable